# Struts 2 example not working

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I am new to struts2. I was trying a small application for practice but I hit an issue.

I was trying to forward directly from index.jsp to `login.jsp`. I know I can directly forward to login.jsp but the below code should also be valid. I am attaching the code I was trying.
below is the code from what I was trying.

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
       <jsp:forward page="login.action" />
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
<include file="example.xml"/>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login">
        <result>/login.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

login.jsp

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form>
        <s:textfield name="user" label="User Name" />
        <s:password name="passwd" label="Password" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

In web.xml the index.php page is set as welcome page. Suppose XYZ is the context name, when I put `/XYZ/login` its take to login page but when I put `/XYZ/`in the browser it give and resource not found error.

when I use `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=login.action">` again it works fine.

I am using tomcat7 as a web server. Why is this happening?

Comment: try setting welcome page as index.jsp in web.xml

Comment: I have done that already. It does come to index.jsp and give the error

Comment: try response.sendRedirect("login");

Comment: I have done that already. It does come to index.jsp and give the error `The requested resource (/XYZ/login.action) is not available`.

Comment: My question is why this is not working. What is the problem with the above code?

Comment: it is trying to access /XYZ/login.action this URL, but it wont work try to access with /XYZ/login URL.

Comment: I changed the line to `<jsp:forward page="login" />` but still the same. and the error is `The requested resource (/S2P2/login) is not available.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the containers by default perform FORWARD to non-JSP resources - `<jsp:forward/>` - to say container to do it please add the following mapping to web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: It worked. can you elaborate about this. I want to know why. I will mark this answered.

Comment: I don't why - maybe some performance issues, security - please check the docs for given container or ask on the mailing list.